# PDF or Other "report viewer" options for Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, pdf

I'm in a bind with my current project. It's a payroll application and I'm developing in ASP.net webforms with C#. My boss said that the ideal function of this site is to click on the pay check date, and a PDF opens and shows the paycheck information. I have done research for a few days to try to find the best solution. So far, I have had no luck. I have found a few different things such as iTextSharp but the license for one year is too expensive right now. I have also seen the tcpdf which is php based. I have also looked into CrystalReports, and Active Reports. To purchase the license is too expensive as well. I have looked into XML to PDF solutions also but I'm not finding anything definite. Since I'm pretty new to the business world of software development and don't have senior developers to rely on, I'm pretty much dead in the water. I know we will be downloading the paychecks into a CSV file from a DOS based application that does our clock-ins and outs. I will then be importing the CSV files into SQL Server 2012 Express. Your ideas are greatly appreciated as I don't know where to go from here! Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you can't afford PDF libraries, output your reports to HTML, and include CSS print stylesheets to make them print nicely.

Comment: @Humpy - Take a look at PDFSharp, http://pdfsharp.com/

Comment: My experience with PDFSharp is that it's too granular, i.e. you need to be too specific about the layout of the PDF, and it's very slow. Better to use a HTML -> PDF converter, like WKHTMLtoPDF

Comment: @Humpy did you have a check on SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS). You can host your reports in the server, and it has options to export to Excel, Pdf or CSV. It comes with SQL Server installation and Visual Studio (Business Intelligence) helps you to edit it

Comment: @RohithNair I have not looked into that yet either. But I will be doing that shortly! Thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

A HTML to PDF converter that I've recently discovered is [WKHTMLtoPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

It's open source and uses WebKit to convert HTML to PDF so it's pretty standards compliant.

An example of how you might use it is

```
using (var pdfStream = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    // pass in the HTML you want to appear in the PDF, and the file stream it writes to
    Printer.GeneratePdf(htmlStream, pdfStream);
}
```

where `GeneratePdf` is defined as

```
    public static void GeneratePdf(Stream html, Stream pdf) 
    {
        Process process;
        StreamWriter stdin;
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

        psi.FileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Lib", "wkhtmltopdf.exe");
        psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName);

        // run the conversion utility
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

        psi.Arguments = "-q -n --disable-smart-shrinking - -";
        process = Process.Start(psi);

        try
        {
            stdin = process.StandardInput;
            stdin.AutoFlush = true;
            //stdin.Write(html.ReadToEnd());
            stdin.Write(new StreamReader(html).ReadToEnd());
            stdin.Dispose();

            process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(pdf);

            process.StandardOutput.Close();
            pdf.Position = 0;

            process.WaitForExit(10000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            process.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

In your case, instead of writing it to a file stream, you'd write it to the HTTP output stream as a PDF.

Please note however, that this example is more suitable to writing PDF files to disk, rather than the output stream so you'd need to do it differently slightly for it to work for you.

Comment: Sweet deal. I'll be looking into these for sure. For some reason, html to PDF never crossed my mind. Thank you!

Comment: It's definitely worth considering because you're dealing with HTML anyway. Basically, you click on the date, the link points to a ASPX page, you code the page to generate the HTML, pass that HTML to the PDF generator, and then Response.Write() that PDF back to the user. You then also have the option of showing the Cheque to the user in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree that html -> pdf is the best option nowadays if you want to render complex report and stay productive.

I have implemented a wrapper for html -> pdf conversion called [jsreport](http://jsreport.net).

If you are using asp.net mvc, you can check out my post [Rendering pdf from Asp.Net MVC views](http://jsreport.net/blog/rendering-pdf-from-aspnet-mvc-views) or more generic post [Pdf reports in c#](http://jsreport.net/blog/pdf-reports-in-csharp).

Disclaimer: I am the author of jsreport