# Convert HTML with CSS to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, itext

I am working in asp.net with C# website. I want to convert a HTML DIV which contains various html elements like divs,label, tables and images with css styles(background color, cssClass etc) and I want its whole content to be converted into PDF using iTextSharp DLL but here I am facing a issue that css is not getting applied.Can any one help me by providing any example or code snippet.

Comment: Do you have to use iTextSharp? I found http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ to very effectively do my HTML -> PDF conversion for free

Comment: Yes...but does wkhtmltopdf work with asp.net and C#?

Comment: I have done this in an mvc c# .net app, using the iTextXmlWorker. If it is of use let me know and i'll post an answer with some info.

Comment: I'm currently using it in a C#/WPF solution, and I don't think it'd be a problem to use it in ASP.NET. This outlines what I've done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18767473/181771

Comment: Please post your code. Are you using `HTMLWorker`? If so, that has long been deprecated in favor of `XmlWorker`. Any and all work, including CSS support, is being done in the latter, don't both even trying the former anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Install 2 NuGet packages iTextSharp and itextsharp.xmlworker and use the following code:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml;


byte[] pdf; // result will be here

var cssText = File.ReadAllText(MapPath("~/css/test.css"));
var html = File.ReadAllText(MapPath("~/css/test.html"));

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
            var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 60, 60);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            document.Open();

            using (var cssMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cssText)))
            {
                using (var htmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
                {
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlMemoryStream, cssMemoryStream);
                }
            }

            document.Close();

            pdf = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Inside css we can use div?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Pechkin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin), a C# wrapper for wkhtmltopdf.

Specifically at this point in time (considering a pending pull request) I'd check out [this fork](https://github.com/tuespetre/Pechkin) that addresses a couple of bugs (particularly helpful in IIS based on my experience).

If you don't go with the fork / get other stability issues you may want to look at having some kind of "render queue" (e.g. in a database) and have a background process (e.g. Windows service) periodically run over the queue and render then store the binary content somewhere (either in database as well, or on file system). This depends entirely on your use-case though.

Alternatively [the similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18767473/181771) @DaveDev has comment linked to.