# C# OpenHtmlToPdf missing styles

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf, openhtmltopdf

I'm using OpenHtmlToPdf to convert a html file to a pdf file. This works, but it doesn't support css grid and also doesn't render the svg which is embedded in the html file.
Do you have an idea of how fix this or know any alternative libraries which support svgs and css grid?

Best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert HTML with CSS to PDF using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661018/convert-html-with-css-to-pdf-using-itextsharp) This uses itextsharp library (I'm not familiar w/ OpenHtmlToPdf)

Comment: @Mikael Thank you for your response! I tried iTextSharp, but some css is missing too (like the grid layout, padding) and the svg is not rendered at all. So, basically the same problem